# Gitlab-CI, Deploy MySQL / PHP Website locally

Tags: gitlab, gitlab-ci, gitlab-ci-runner

We currently have a local instance of Gitlab running on a Debian Machine at work and want to locally deploy the project via the .gitlab-ci.yml.

Since I am fairly new to gitlab and continuous integration in general I am rather lost here.

The project itself only consists out of some .php files, within the root directory which also create a MySQL database, and after someone pushed something, the Website should be deployed locally under `xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx/Website` to view it.

Is this even possible with the gitlab-ci? Any help would be greatly appriciated.

Answer (score 3):

To keep it simple; You should [install](https://docs.gitlab.com/runner/install/linux-repository.html) a [Gitlab-CI runner](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab-ci-multi-runner) on your target machine, [register](https://docs.gitlab.com/runner/register/index.html) it with your Gitlab instance and configure it as a [Shell executor](https://docs.gitlab.com/runner/executors/shell.html).

Then, if you use `.gitlab-ci.yml` commands to move your files to the directory that matches `xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx/Website` and run some config there or before you move the files you can view the result.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. We currently have a shared runner available, another problem is, the local instance of GitLab also runs under the local `xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx` address.

Comment: You should really avoid that I guess. Or run another webserver / vhost under a different port. Though that's quite nasty. A simple VM or something for deploying would be way better.

Comment: The gitlab instance is already in a VM which also holds the runner. I was currently looking into kubernetes, if there is a possibility to do it that way.